# Java - Different Resolutions, Same Coordinates

Tags: java, graphics, window, coordinate-systems

I would like the user of my software to resize the window that is presented to them when they launch the application. I can make the graphics of the game or application resize fine but I can't quite get the coordinates to be the same on every different size. If I have a collision detection box at 50,50 with the dimensions of 50,50. Of course the graphics are at those coordinates. But when I resize it the box stays in the same place but the graphic moves according to resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you resize the window, the size of the window changes, but the coordinates do not change.**

What you need to do is register a listener to changing size, get the current size and change the coordinates of your detection box.